# Why the accuracy and binary_accuracy in keras have same result?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I created a simple model for binary classification with Keras. The code is:

```py
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(250, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'binary_accuracy'])
```

My purpose was check the result of `accuracy` and `binary_accuracy` is understand difference between them.

As Keras says `binary_accuracy` accuracy have threshold that default is `.5`, that `accuracy' haven't. When I test them with sample data the result is difference but in the train of model thy have same results in each epoch.

for this true and predicted sample I tested `accuracy` and `binary_accuracy`:

```py
   y_true = [[1], [1], [0], [0]]
   y_pred = [[0.51], [1], [0], [0.4]]
```

For  `binary_accuracy` is:

```py
m = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
m.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
m.result().numpy()
```

that result is:
`1`

For  `accuracy` is:

```py
m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
m.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
m.result().numpy()
```

and the result is:
'.5'

But in the above model it is same for each of them in each epoch.

**Edit**

By changing the compile to this the result changed:

```py
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=.7)])
```

Why `accuracy` work like `binary_accuracy` with `threshold=0.5` in model but not in out of model?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to `tf.keras.Model.compile()` documentation:

> When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one of tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy based on the loss function used and the model output shape. We do a similar conversion for the strings 'crossentropy' and 'ce' as well.

In your case it was transformed to BinaryAccuracy and hence result is the same.

However `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy` is something completely different. If you read the documentation:

> Calculates how often predictions equal labels.

which means it looks at unique values of `y_pred` and `y_true` and treats every unique value as a distinct label. In your case 0.51 and 0.4 are treated as a separate labels and because they are not equal to 1 and 0, respectively, you get 0.5

Apologies for marking this question as a duplicate at first, the behaviour is different in `tf.keras` than in `keras` package

Comment: thanks a lot. then evaluate do this? it use `threshold=0.5`? and when we use predict and other threshold the accuracy changes?

Comment: when evaluating you should use the same threshold. If you change threshold, the accuracy naturally changes. When performing inference, classification threshold can be adjusted to suit your needs, that is, balancing True Positives and True Negatives